# Prevent outgoing email spam from client's VPS

Tags: email, vps

I have a dedicated server with a few VPSs for my clients. I'd like to immediately stop/suspend any VPS that send out mass emails.

I'm aware of a way to monitor SMTP connections on port 25 But this method doesn't work if the VPSs are configured to use another port to send out email.

I'm not sure if the method works if the client use `mail()` function in PHP, though.

I'd love to hear your opinion about the available methods that works great to prevent spam.

Thanks for any sharing!

**Additional information:**

I'm using Proxmox, my clients have openVZ VPS and LXC containers. I have access to guest system, but prefer not to use the access privileges since the clients may re-configure anything in the way they want.

Comment: The right answer depends on your setup (what kind of virtualization do you have, do you have access to guest system, etc.)

Comment: @Pavel Kazhevets, I have updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenVZ and LXC it is much easier task than for KVM, for example. You can use some already written tools like [this](https://github.com/FastVPSEestiOu/linux_network_smtp_tracker) and [this](https://github.com/FastVPSEestiOu/linux_network_activity_tracker) (FastVPS specializes on OpenVZ VPSes).

Also, having access to guest system, you can not only monitor traffic from outside, but you also can monitor smtp queue from inside. And this can be much more efficient. From my practice, I can say that usually you'll have pretty common MTA installed (sendmail/exim/postfix).

You can write script that will jump into container, detect MTA used and get size of queue. Having that data you'll be able to see abnormal activities and with php `mail()` function you'll also will be able to detect particular script that is sending spam from `X-PHP-Originating-Script` header (refer [here](http://ericheikes.com/tracing-spam-from-php-scripts/)).

Regretfully, there is no silver bullet in fight against spam. So, you need to automate things as much as possible. For that purpose you can send alerts from you smap-in-queue-detencting script both to you and to VPS owner. In most cases there are just some infection caused by outdated or misconfigured CMS (like Wordpress or Joomla) and some giving VPS owner some recomendations to mitigate spam (like updating CMS, running `maldet`, etc.) can help you.

**EDIT:**

For case with KVM or any other case where you don't have access to guest system there is no convenient ways to mitigate spam activities, but still you have some options. Some of them will be unacceptable due to privacy policy.

1. Provide OS images for KVM with preinstalled monitoring agent and/or user with public key imported that will be used for purposes of monitoring and controlling spam. If this option is acceptable to you, then you can use the same steps as with OpenVZ to monitor queue and detect spam-generating php scripts.
2. Block or rate-limit traffic going out from public IPs and port common to SMTP protocol (usually 25). Some giant providers (for example, Amazon) have rate-limiting on port 25 enabled by default and to disable it you need to write request to support with description of your use-case.

Comment: Thank you, @Pavel Kazhevets, your explanation is very in-dept. It would be better if you can give some explaination about the KVM case, to make the topic more complete :)